# Heating water with electricity

Tags: heat, water, electricity

Is it possible to raise the temperature of water almost instantaneously  Using electricity ? I want to raise the temperature of tap water to 180 degrees F.

Comment: Obviously, since any kettle does this.

Comment: True but what I'm going for is heating the water as quickly as possible kettles take time I want a faster process.

Comment: One does not simply heat water to 82 degrees Celsius instantaneously. You need a large surface area if you want to do that.

Comment: Really? Tankless water heaters heat water heaters do so pretty quickly using propane most times. I'm not scientist so I'm not trying to offend just trying to figure out if there is a way to accomplish this safely and quickly. Seems like it's not possible :/

Comment: Your problem is that you don't know how to ask what _could_ be a simple question. You don't have to be a scientist for that.

Comment: Well if u have the answer then point me In the right direction

Comment: Rough order of magnitude Fermi estimation you will need about 32 kilowatts of power to heat faucet water. Not an implausible about of power with a dedicated industrial circuit but  getting it all into the water fast is tricky, (estimate based on 8 liter per minute flow rate,  or 8 kg of water per minute divided by 60 to get seconds times 60 to indicate raising temperature by 60 degrees times 4 for 4 joules per calorie)

Comment: $$P = \frac{mc\Delta T}{t}$$ Where \$P\$ is power required, \$m\$ is mass of water, \$c\$ is specific thermal capacity of water, \$\Delta T\$ is temperature rise, and \$t\$ is time to change temperature (all SI units - i.e. *C not *F). Basic high school physics.

Comment: This is not an electrical engineering problem it is primarily a problem of thermodynamics and heat transfer. To start, you need to know the  temperature of the incoming water and the expected rate of flow. You need to quantify "almost instantaneously."

Comment: @user121223 I've already given you an answer. My kettle can heat water to its boiling point almost instantly. You have failed to define both a volume, time span or power requirements, so it's impossible to give an answer to _your_ question. "As quickly as possible", "almost instantaneously", such phrases are meaningless.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not an electrical engineering problem, it is not well defined and no prior research is evident.

Comment: I investigated this at school for a D&T O-level in 1974, and found a solution (no www back then :-). This question shows no research effort. The OP is arguing the comments are inadequate, so it is clearly underspecified. Please read the [help] to understand how to ask good questions. Hint: a passenger train provides a continuous stream of heated water for the toilet washbasins.

Comment: "using propane" 20-40kw or more on demand is not difficult. Using mains electricity, especially at 110V, it's a bit harder.

Answer (score 6):

You can roughly calculate how much power is required to do this.

$$P = \frac{mc\Delta T}{t}$$

Where \$P\$ is power required, \$m\$ is mass of water, \$c\$ is specific thermal capacity of water, \$\Delta T\$ is temperature rise, and \$t\$ is time to change temperature (all SI units - i.e. \$^\circ\mathrm{C}\$ not \$^\circ\mathrm{F}\$).

This is in fact a basic high school physics equation. Plug in your numbers and you get a rough estimate of the required power. The thermal capacity for water is roughtly \$4.184\space \mathrm{Jg^{-1}K^{-1}}\$. So doing a quick example, lets say you want to heat \$1\mathrm{l}\$ of water by \$60^\circ\mathrm{C}\$ (assuming water starts at room temp) in lets say \$1\mathrm{s}\$ as you give no time.

Plug all the numbers in, you get:

$$P = \frac{mc\Delta T}{t} = \frac{1000\mathrm{g} \times 4.184 \mathrm{Jg^{-1}K^{-1}} \times 60^\circ\mathrm{K}}{1\mathrm{s}} = 251\mathrm{kW}$$

Quite a lot of power there. Perhaps you should plug in some more reasonable values.

Whether or not it is possible will depend on whether or not you can transfer the required amount of power to the water in the required amount of time. I can't say whether that is possible or not as I don't know how much water you are trying to heat and how fast you are trying to heat it in.

Comment: The downvote is a tad harsh - care to explain the issue?

Comment: I also think it was harsh +1

Comment: @TomCarpenter Nice question, excellent answer.